# How to inform the Android media store about new file in Flutter

Tags: flutter

How to inform the Android media store about new file in Downlods directory.
By default the file is not shown in smartphone Dowloads dir when looking for it from a regular computer. The file was written there from Flutter app. The file is not hidden, it is visible on smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like the Flutter documentation has anything about this as yet. Hopefully it will be a feature at some point. There are a lot of changes to how the Media Store works this year so perhaps the devs will do something about it then.

The only work arounds I've seen is to call native android functions via Kotlin. If you have a look at the src of this package it should make things clearer... Not the most satisfying answer I'm sure.

[media_store](https://pub.dev/packages/media_store)